# Необычное поведение java.util.logging. Дублирование сообщения

Tags: java

Кто-нибудь может мне объяснить, почему при наличии статического блока инициализации, логер дублирует сообщение в консоле?

**Java Code:**

```
public class LoggerProxy {

    private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Example.class.getName());

    /*static */{ // <- при наличии static, сообщение дублируется
        log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
        log.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());
    }

    public static void info(String msg){
        log.info(messageFormat(new Exception(msg)));
    }

    public static void info(Exception ex){
        log.info(messageFormat(ex));
    }

    private static String messageFormat(Exception ex){
        StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement = ex.getStackTrace();

        int index = 1;

        return String.format(
                "[%s/%s.%s()]: %s",
                stackTraceElement[index].hashCode(),
                stackTraceElement[index].getClassName(),
                stackTraceElement[index].getMethodName(),
                ex.getMessage() // OR -> ex.getLocalizedMessage()
        );
}


    public static void config(String msg){...}
    public static void config(Exception ex){...}
    public static void fine(String msg){...}
    public static void fine(Exception ex){...}
    public static void finer(String msg){...}
    public static void finer(Exception ex){...}
    public static void finest(String msg){...}
    public static void finest(Exception ex){...}
    public static void severe(String msg){...}
    public static void severe(Exception ex){...}
    public static void warning(String msg){...}
    public static void warning(Exception ex){...}
    public static void addHandler(Handler handler){...}
    public static void removeHandler(Handler handler){...}
}
```

**Console:**

```
// при наличии static в блоке инициализации
мая 02, 2018 7:17:25 ПП LoggerProxy info
INFO: ...
мая 02, 2018 7:17:25 ПП LoggerProxy info
INFO: ...

// при отсутствии static в блоке инициализации
мая 02, 2018 7:17:25 ПП LoggerProxy info
INFO: ...
```

Comment: Попробуй закомментировать строку `log.addHandler(new ConsoleHandler());`

Comment: Эх, мне стоило разобраться с блоком инициализации чуточку лучше... Во-первых, я забыл, что динамический блок инициализации выполняется только тогда, когда создается экземпляр класса. Во-вторых, я не знал, что по умолчанию в Logger стоит обработчик ConsoleHandler и повторное его добавление ведет к дублированию сообщения. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, по умолчанию в Logger стоит обработчик ConsoleHandler и повторное его добавление ведет к дублированию сообщения.

Во-вторых, динамический блок инициализации обрабатывается при создании экземпляра класса.

В итоге должно быть следующее.

```
. . .

static{
    log.setLevel(Level.ALL);
}

. . .
```